# :set spell doesn't highlight php files

Tags: neovim

When I use `:set spell` in a php file, nothing is highlighted. But I can use `:syn off` to see the highlighted words.

Some other file formats, like for example my init.vim file, show simultaneously the syntax highlight and the spelling highlight.

The issue persists when I remove all of my configs from `~/.config/nvim`

Comment: This is probably due to the syntax highlighting definitions conflicting with the spell checking highlighting. Without your `init.vim` it will be impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: The issue persists when I completely get rid of my own configs under `~/.config/nvim`, so I have no `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. I can verify with `:scriptnames` that the only settings loaded are under `/usr/share/nvim/runtime`, which are the default installation files.

Comment: I see. In this case, I suggest heading over to the Neovim project on GitHub and open an issue there, detailing the steps you took.